# Geo Pandas Installation Issue on Windows 10 (PyCharm)

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, anaconda

1.[Console Pandas installation in Pycharm Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CacRl.png)

2.[Console Pandas installation in Pycharm Part 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpXCn.png)

I have MiniAnaconda installed, and I'm trying to run some scripts to update my repository, but I keep getting the Pandas installation error (despite my interpreter showing it's installed). When I attempt to install this, the error I get from the command terminal is attached in the images. I have Python 3.11 installed. Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Installation of Pandas pkg

```
C:\Users\xx>conda activate C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\pxxxx
 
(pxxx) C:\Users\xxx>conda activate C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\pxxxx
 
(pxxx) C:\Users\xxxx>C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\miniconda3\condabin\conda.bat install -p C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/miniconda3/envs/pxxxx geopandas~=0.14.0 -y
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1061: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'cn-1998264036-vnsg12428.ibosscloud.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
Channels:
- defaults
- conda-forge
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed
 
LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package geopandas-0.14.2-py311haa95532_0 requires geopandas-base 0.14.2 py311haa95532_0, but none of the providers can be installed
 
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ geopandas-base 0.13.2.*  is requested and can be installed;
├─ geopandas ~=0.14.0  is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ geopandas 0.14.2 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ geopandas 0.14.2 would require
│  │  └─ geopandas-base 0.14.2 py311haa95532_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ geopandas 0.14.2 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.12,<3.13.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ geopandas 0.14.2 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ geopandas 0.14.0 would require
│  │  └─ geopandas-base 0.14.0 pyha770c72_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ geopandas 0.14.0 would require
│  │  └─ geopandas-base 0.14.0 pyha770c72_1, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ geopandas 0.14.1 would require
│  │  └─ geopandas-base 0.14.1 pyha770c72_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ geopandas 0.14.2 would require
│  │  └─ geopandas-base 0.14.2 pyha770c72_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  └─ geopandas 0.14.3 would require
│     └─ geopandas-base 0.14.3 pyha770c72_0, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.11.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.
 
Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
- python 3.11.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```